# Adding commas to numbers, replacing characters and adding a space all in one regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Javascript:

```
condition.replace(/([<=])/,'$1 ').replace(/>=/,'≥').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/,'$1,');
```

Can this be combined in one single replace?

Results: '>=1000' → '≥ 1,000', '=100000' → '= 100,000', '<10000' → '< 10,000'

Comment: how about `condition.replace(/(>=)((\d)(?=(\d{3})+$))/,'$1 $2,')`?

Comment: What is the benefit of combining it into a single regex? I would keep them separate for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hardly think so, or if so, that'd be pretty dexterous, which I'm not sure how it would be done. My guess is that these two expressions might simply do the job:

```
>=(\d+)(?=\d{3}$)
```

with a replacement of:

```
≥ $1,
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/D82D79/1/)

---

and:

```
^(=|<)(\d+)(?=\d{3}$)
```

with the same replacement of:

```
$1 $2,
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/hK17vo/1/)